# How to have DecimalFields without explicitly mentioning decimal_places and max_digits as in Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I plan to have the following table in Postgres

```
create table Transaction (
    tax_amount decimal
);
```

I wish not to specific number of digits explicitly.

For Django model, I use

```
tax_amount = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm getting error

```
billing.Transaction.tax_amount: (fields.E130) DecimalFields must define a 'decimal_places' attribute.
billing.Transaction.tax_amount: (fields.E132) DecimalFields must define a 'max_digits' attribute.
```

I was wondering, how can I have Django translated to equivalent Postgres SQL, without mentioning `decimal_places` and `max_digits` explicitly?

Comment: Are you sure this is something that can't be done with FloatField?

Comment: We haven't tried that. As, we prefer Python to use Decimal instead of float. We are dealing to monetary value, and don't expect 1.1 + 2.2 to become 3.3000000000000003

Comment: So if you storing decimal values why do you want to leave the number of decimal fields blank? It ought to be two